# when specifying firefox as the default open program for swf files, Windows 10 prompted "The file cannot be accessed by the system"

Tags: firefox

It seems that the firefox.exe is stowed in some really deep folders. See below.

I tried all firefox.exe listed for being configured as the default open executable for my flash games but all got me the same error prompt in the title.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Adobe Flash Player](https://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/updaters/32/flashplayer_32_sa.exe) is still available to download. It lies in the old domain from Macromedia (fpdownload.macromedia.com).

Comment: Many thanks. I suspect the FF issue is due to some security policy.

Comment: [It is!](https://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/end-of-life.html)